# php Error:SMTP connect(); failed

Tags: php, email, openssl

I am trying out to send mail from PHP using SMTP, but I am getting the error `Error:SMTP connect(); failed`.

I checked everything in the server and it's all OK.

When I try to send mail from another domain the mails are going out OK, but when I try the same code on the actual host machine (i.e the SMTP server) to send mail I get the above error.

Here is my SMTP Configuration.

```
define("EMAIL_USE_SMTP", true);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_HOST", "mail.myhosthome.com");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH", true);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME", "XXXXXXXXXX@myhosthome.com");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PORT", 2525);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION", "ssl");
```

Comment: Is it possible that the local machine does not recognize the domain name? Have you tried using "localhost" as as SMTP_HOST or tried to ping the domain name from the email server?

Comment: @Henkealg yes but still i am getting the same error,

Comment: Ok, have you checked the server logs for any for any additional details on the error you have posted in you question? And have you mede sure that port 2525 is accepted also from localhost? That can be tested using telnet from the server terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Update your certificates. You are either using an expired certificate or the CA chain cannot be verified by the openssl library. You can test with openssl from the command line.